# Giving requirements to front end developers

Tags: requirements

Is there an industry standard in communicating requirements to front end developers?

I have a project coming up where I will have annotated wireframes that will have front end dev input and complete designs. I normally work with back end developers and use User Stories as part of a Scrum setup but am unsure whether this is the best way to present these requirements to a front end dev given the nature of the task.

Thanks

Comment: Have you asked your front-end developers how they would like to receive the requirements?

Comment: Of course,some preferred user stories who were use to a Scrum setup where as others preferred annotated wireframes who were less familiar with Scrum. I have asked around and there appears to be no industry standard way of communicating these front end requirements, all dependent on the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a Scrum methodology then I think it makes sense to continue using the same approach for both front-end and back-end developers. User stories are a perfectly legitimate and effective way to communicate requirements for both groups. The benefit to you as the project manager is consistency in terms of requirements creation, management and review.

If you are concerned that some deliverables (e.g. annotated wireframes) are non-functional and thus unsuited to user story creation you may find [Mike Cohn's article on this subject](http://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/non-functional-requirements-as-user-stories) useful.

Mark Phillips' point is correct though - you definitely need to get the people who will *do* the work involved in making decisions about how that work is defined.

Comment: If you're using a Scrum methodology then ideally your back-end and front-end developers are on the *same team* anyway...